# Magento Enterprise Rewards Points Set up rule

Tags: magento-enterprise

How is possible in magento Enterprise if order value in cart is $xx than customer earn Y rewards points.Means "Points are accrued when orders over £150".
Thanks,

Comment: Is anybody have any Idea for this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Magento Enterprise edition and have access to their Reward system you can try the following:

Enable the Reward module in your config.
Go to Customer > Reward Exchange Rates
and add two rates: 
1. Currency to points: 150 => 1
2. points to currency: 1 => 1

This would mean that you will get 1 point per £150 the customer spends, and that 1 point is the same value than £1 (which I assumed).

Else you would have to extend the functionality of the module yourself, ie. add new rules to the reward module.

This stackoverflow question might interest you as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743341/payment-using-reward-points-not-showing-up-on-checkout-in-magento-enterprise-edi

I hope that helps a little.